# Attachment shows correct _contentType, but contentUrl is null, why?

Tags: c#, google-mirror-api

When I retrieve a timeline item, it shows there is an attachment and a correct content type, but ContentUrl is null, why?
I also tried by getting timelineResource.GetRequest and changing the Alt as "media", but it returns error (400).

[image]

Comment: I got it, you need to call get.                                   Attachment attachment = Program.Service.Timeline.Attachments.Get (tli.Id, tli.Attachments[0].Id).Fetch ();

Answer (score 3):

You have to retrieve the full meta information of the attachment with a `timeline.attachments.get` request using the `Id` you got in the `timeline.get` request. The result will contain the `ContentUrl` which you can then use the retrieve the data for the attachment.

https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/attachments/get

I'm not sure what the reasoning behind not showing the contentUrl directly in the timeline item is, you might want to add a new issue to the [Glass issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) to suggest a different behaviour.